# Sync iPod Touch Automatically when on WiFi but not plugged in

Tags: itunes, wifi, ipod-touch

I haven't seen this addressed anywhere, and I sort of understand why Apple would implement this but I want to see if there's any work around I haven't found yet.

Basically, I have an iPod Touch I keep in my car's glove compartment hooked up to my stereo.  The auto wifi sync only works when plugged in, but I would love for every time my ipod connects to my network for it to sync.

Currently, I can manually do it, and I have an Applescript that tries to sync every night, but that only works about 10% of the time.  Is there any automation apps or other work around you have found that will allow me to never have to take my ipod out of the glove compartment yet sync every time it is able?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know *why* the AppleScript rarely works? I could suggest many scripts that'd sync it, but I'm unsure as to what exactly doesn't work with your script.

Comment: @grgarside The iOS device won't connect to the WiFi network when not powered and left in the glovebox. That would be responsible for most of the failures to sync. You can force a sync from the car when you arrive assuming iTunes is always running, but that involves opening the glovebox and tapping a few times.

Comment: @grgarside Yes, it has nothing to do with the applescript I wrote.  Even if my iTunes shows the iPod, clicking to sync only sometimes works.  Other times it looks like it works for about 30 secs and then the iPod disappears from the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to jailbreak, you can install [**Wi-Fi Sync**](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.ghughes.wifisync).

This is a jailbreak tweak invented before Apple implemented the actual iTunes Wi-Fi Sync, and can be scripted with AppleScript to sync whenever you want it scheduled.